# Array.count with block does not return correct answer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of Assignment objects that I create from a database call:

```
@assignments = @player.assignments
```

I want to count them with this:

```
@assignments.count {|x| x.sets == 0.0}
```

This should count the number of assignments with 0.0 sets. However, this always returns the total number of objects in @assignments. I have checked that

```
@assignments.each {|x| puts x.sets == 0.0}
```

does not return true in all the cases.
Any clues?

Edit>

```
@assignments.map(&:sets)
=> [35.0, 120.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 12.0, 75.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Comment: Use `select` first and then `count`.

Comment: Can you show the output of `@assignments.map(&:sets)` ?

Comment: It works for me
    `[1] pry(main)> assignments = [35.0, 120.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 12.0, 75.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
=> [35.0, 120.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 12.0, 75.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[2] pry(main)> assignments.count {|x| x == 0.0}
=> 9
[3] pry(main)> assignments.count
=> 13`

Comment: This works  for me too

   a = [35.0, 120.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 12.0, 75.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] 
     => [35.0, 120.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 12.0, 75.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] 
    
    a.count {|x| x == 0.0}
     => 9

Comment: Is this just Ruby, or is Rails involved too?

Comment: ok, it's a has_many association. No doubt it's the not-real-array Array problem then.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Most likely, `@assignments` is not an `Array` instance, but `ActiveRecord::Relation`, try `@assignments.class`. If so, `count` method does not work as you expected, it returns numbers of records.

Try

```
@assignments.where(sets: 0).count
```

Or even (convert to array first)

```
@assignments.to_a.count {|x| x.sets == 0.0}
```

Comment: It is returned by a Rails ActiveRecord method. But @assignments.class returns Array.
But your solution worked for me, so I guess it is as you say.
Thank you very much!

Comment: @user1742188: Rails 2? It may say "Array" but it's not a plain array. One of the innumerable hacks that fortunately are being solved in latests versions.

Comment: Its Rails 3.2.8. Gah. Thanks for the info tokland.
This was seriously crazy. The documentation should note such exceptions.

Comment: @user1742188: Paste in the question how you create `@assignments`. That Array thing is documented somewhere.

Comment: `.all` was still returning `ActiveRecord::Relation` for me. I had to use `.all.to_a`.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

```
    @assignments.select {|x| x if x.sets == 0.0}.count
```

Thanks

Comment: This answer works for when you want to use a method to return the count. Meaning, if you're not counting based on an object's attribute, but rather based on a method. For instance: `people.select {|person| person if person.tall?}.count`

Comment: @singularity `.select(<block>).count` is really the same as `count(<block>)`, just a little more verbose.

Answer (score 0):

see count or each just count the number of objects only(internally it checks for each object as if object will be present it will return true if its `nill` will return false, so actually it counts the number of `true` that are returned by the block), if you want to count the number of times your condition holds true i suggest you try using the `inject` iterator that is made for these type of computations only in the ruby.

It will be like this

```
@assignments.inject(0) {|sum,x| 
  if x.sets == 0.0
    sum + 1
  else
    sum
  end
}
```

Comment: [not true, atleast for ruby's count](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-count)

Comment: @user1742188 will you try this one too once.

Comment: In that case you should edit your answer accordingly, since as I say, the default `count` works exactly as OP wants it to